# Object inheritance in Neo4j hibernate OGM

Tags: jpa, neo4j, hibernate-ogm

I'm doing a POC on a Hibernate OGM implementation for Neo4j.  In doing this, I've created the following objects:

```
@Entity
public class AutoDealership {


private String name;

public AutoDealership(String nam){
    this.name = nam;
}
@Id
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

private void setName(String n){
    name = n;
}

private List<Vehicle> vehicle = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="autoDealership")
public List<Vehicle> getVehicle(){
    return vehicle;
}

private void setVehicles(List<Vehicle> v){
    this.vehicle = v;
}

}
```

And a Vehicle class:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

protected AutoDealership autoDealership;
abstract int getValue();

@ManyToOne
public abstract AutoDealership getAutoDealership();

private void setValue(int v){

}
}
```

Which is extended into classes that have simple implementations.  I run this code as follows:

```
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        OgmSession session =em.unwrap(OgmSession.class);
        Camry camry1 = new Camry("Joe");
        Camry camry2 = new Camry("Elvis");
        Silverado s = new Silverado("TX");
        Maserati mas = new Maserati();
        mas.setStatus("Massive");
        session.saveOrUpdate(camry1);
        session.saveOrUpdate(camry2);
        session.saveOrUpdate(s);
        session.saveOrUpdate(mas);
        AutoDealership a = new AutoDealership("Slick Willie's");
        session.saveOrUpdate(a);
        camry1.setAutoDealership(a);
        camry2.setAutoDealership(a);
        mas.setAutoDealership(a);
        s.setAutoDealership(a);
        tx.commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
```

When I run this, it fails with :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ogm-neo4j] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1239)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:855)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:62)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at dogs.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:22)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: cars.AutoDealership.vehicle[cars.Vehicle]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1134)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:793)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:728)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
```

If I comment out anything related to getting the vehicles from AutoDealership, the code compiles and works, and successfully inserts nodes into the database.  I've tried to change the mappedBy target to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was that I had to declare Vehicle as an Entity.